# apply function to more variables php

Tags: php, function, variables, eregi

Newbie question

i have following function:

```
function isadult($description)
{
$bad=/*comma separated bad words*/;
$bad=explode(",",$bad);
foreach($bad as $key)
{
if(eregi($key,$description))
{
return true;
}
}
return false;
}  


if (isadult($description)) exit;
else
```

this function apply only to variable `$description` if i want apply this function also to variable `$title` how to modify function ?
and `eregi` is deprecated how to change eregi with `preg_match` ?

thanks

Comment: just call the function a second time?like: `if (isadult($description) || isadult($title)) ...`

Comment: why using `$bad=explode(",",$bad);` when you can use `$bad = array('word1','word2'...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send both the `$description` and the `$title` variable to the function. The variable name provided in the function declaration is only refering to the variable name within the function scope, and not any variable names outside the function, even if they happen to be identical (as with `$description` in your case).

Try `if(isadult($title)) {` and you will find that it will work.

The value of the *external variable* `$title` is put into the *function variable* `$description`, and will be referred to as `$description` within the function scope (between *{* and *}*)

---

Since you're not doing any actual regular expression matching in your example, you could just as well replace `eregi()` with `stripos()`, `stristr()` or similar...

```
if(stripos($description, $key) !== false) {
```

---

You should also define your bad words list as an array right away, instead of having php converting it.

```
$bad = array('badword1','badword2','badword3');
```

Comment: They were some of the actual words used in the example, but they've been edited away.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

newbies should read the doc ;)